# How come the Antarctic REMA Explorer say its 108,66 km from 90°S to 89°S?

Tags: latitude-longitude, wgs84

I am trying to understand the calculation for distance at the Antartic REMA Explorer site:
https://livingatlas2.arcgis.com/antarcticdemexplorer/

Zooming in, selecting the measure tool and doing a measure from the South Pole to 89 degrees in any direction returns the distance of about 108,66 km.
(Do one measurement and then select "Distance" to focus on distance measuring instead of elevation)
The map uses WGS84 for its coordinates.

All math I have come across says that the distance should be about 111,694 km between 90 and 89 degrees.

**I'm simply trying to understand how to make calculations and get 108,66 km myself.**
I have a mesh built based on that map, and need to perform the same calculations to accurately place objects on the mesh based on Lat/Lon.

If it turns out that the calculations in the REMA Explorer is incorrect, then I guess it may be of interest to some.

Comment: What method are you using to compute the distance? Great circle distance, chordal distance, Euclidean distance? Depending on how you are accounting for the curvature of the earth (or not), the mathematically computed distance will vary.

Comment: Distance measuring depends on geoid, projection, and if you account for elevation so the result you get may be the "right" one in this specific setting

Comment: I tried a bunch of tools and they all agree with you. For example this one that allows to select the geoid https://geodesyapps.ga.gov.au/vincenty-inverse. However, the REMA Explorer seems to be made for visualization mainly.

Comment: The standard parallel is at 71 degrees S latitude: https://epsg.org/crs_3031/WGS-84-Antarctic-Polar-Stereographic.html.  This causes distances at more extreme latitudes (near the center) to be shortened and other distances to be lengthened.  (The orientation doesn't matter, because this is a conformal projection.)  Evidently, then, the app is measuring distance *in the map* rather than on the Earth and scaling that measured distance up to approximate the actual distance.

Comment: To test this I created a simple C# console app, I've tried more or less all nuget packages that have the wgs84 tag. And a few other libraries as well. I have given all of them the task to caluclate the distance between -90 and -89 degrees (0 elevation in the cases where the libraries supported that). Here are some of the results
111290,919753418
111693,864914267
111693,864914267
111693,864914266
111194,9
111693,864914309 
111,31945589 
111,125113474479
As you can see all of them are above 111.
I ended up making a library of my own using a table of values to do the calcs on.
Thx

Answer (score 1):

The web map seems to use WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic coordinate system https://epsg.org/crs_3031/WGS-84-Antarctic-Polar-Stereographic.html. The scope of the coordinate system is "Antarctic Digital Database and small scale topographic mapping." Probably it is not meant for accurate distance measurements.

There is another rather similar web map at https://www.add.scar.org/ that allows user to select between geodesic distances and projected distances.

Comment: This is my conclusion as well. Which is why I ended up with a totally different approach to get the values I needed. Thanks for the effort trying to help me.